# How to replace "Lock Screen" option with another command in MATE

Tags: mate-desktop

I dont want to use mate-screensaver for several reasons, but I use the MATE desktop environment. I can replace the screensaver/lock screen with a different program to auto lock my screen, but in the "System" menu in the panel, if you select "Lock Screen", it doesen't lock the screen, because I uninstalled mate-screensaver and if it wasn't uninstalled, it would lock the screen with mate-screensaver, which is - what I don't wan't. How does one edit the "Lock Screen" command in the mate "System" menu?

Comment: Two years later, no help? I'm having the identical issue. I can't even find out what file to edit.